# Filter result of sql procedure against current datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one procedure called **GetScheduleWithNextRunTime** which will result datetime values where schedule need to run next as below

[image]

Now I would like to filter this result against current date to get records which nextscheduletime within minute.

Comment: If you can't alter your Stored Procedure, you will have to get the result of your Stored Procedure into a (temporary) table, in order to filter it. Try searching here on Stack Overflow on how to do that, or click here for the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @date as DATETIME = GETDATE()

SELECT RowId, Sid, NextScheduleTime
FROM yourTable
WHERE NextScheduleTime BETWEEN @date AND DATEADD(mi, 1, @date)
```